# How to use print to display class instances in python

Tags: python, class, for-loop, instance-variables

I am trying to print instances of a class, however I get a result that seems to be in the correct format but is not the output I am looking for.

I  have used def **str**(self) as someone recommend but I am still getting the same result

This is the entire code:

```
class Employee:

    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.name = name 
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1
    def __str__(self):
        print (self.name)
    def displayCount(self):
        print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name : ", self.name, ", Salary: ",self.salary)
global emp1
global emp2
global n
global s
emp1 = ''
emp2 = ''
alist = [emp1,emp2]
alist_final =[]
for y in alist:
    y = Employee('n',2)
    alist_final.append(y)
    y.displayEmployee()
    print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)



print(alist_final)
```

This is the result i get on the command line:

```
C:\Users\Demi\Desktop\virtuallearner>pr.py
z
2
Name :  z , Salary:  2
Total Employee 1
m
5
Name :  m , Salary:  5
Total Employee 2
[<__main__.Employee object at 0x0000022AFA278550>, <__main__.Employee object 
at 0x0000022AFA278550>]
```

I am trying to print out the instances with the changes made in the for loop

Comment: What is the output you *expected*?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

Comment: Worth reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/what-is-the-difference-between-str-and-repr

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to note here.

1. You were not calling the `str` method of the instances. Rather you were calling `print` on the container, which is `alist_final`, which is a list.

   `print(somelist)` will call the str method `somelist`, not the elements in the `list`
2. You were not returning the string representation. Instead of that, you were calling it with `print`.

You need to `return` the representation from the `__str__` method you implemented like,

```
$ cat emp.py
class Employee:

    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.name = name 
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}(name={}, salary={})'.format(
                        self.__class__.__name__,
                        self.name,
                        self.salary)

    def displayCount(self):
        print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name : ", self.name, ", Salary: ",self.salary)


alist_final =[]
for _ in range(2):
    y = Employee('n',2)
    alist_final.append(y)
    y.displayEmployee()
    print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)

print([str(x) for x in alist_final])
```

**Output:**

```
$ python emp.py
('Name : ', 'n', ', Salary: ', 2)
Total Employee 1
('Name : ', 'n', ', Salary: ', 2)
Total Employee 2
['Employee(name=n, salary=2)', 'Employee(name=n, salary=2)']
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **__str__** method, you can use **__repr__** method. Using this method you don't need to explicitly convert the instance into string. Find the code:

```
class Employee:
    empCount = 0
    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def displayCount(self):
        print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print ("Name : ", self.name, ", Salary: ",self.salary)
global emp1
global emp2
global n
global s
emp1 = ''
emp2 = ''
alist = [emp1,emp2]
alist_final =[]
for y in alist:
    y = Employee('n',2)
    alist_final.append(y)
    y.displayEmployee()
    print("Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount)
print(alist_final)
```

Output would be like:

```
Name :  n , Salary:  2
Total Employee 1
Name :  n , Salary:  2
Total Employee 2
[n, n]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @diola.O Please upvote it, if you find helpful so that others would get benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `__repr__` method which will run when a instance of your class is passed into the print function.

```py
def __repr__(self) -> str:
    return f"employee<{name: {self.name}, salary: {self.salary}>"
```